# Is there a way to have a loose interface with SOME strictness?

Tags: typescript

I was hoping I could have an interface like:

```
interface Item {
  [ index: string ] : string | number | Item,
  id: number,
}
```

So that an Item, can have any properties with string/number/object values, BUT-- if an id property is used, it MUST be a number.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I originally asked this, but then tested it out and what I did seems to work fine, UNLESS I am using optional attributes...

If I do this, then I get a typescript error:

```
interface Item {
  [ index: string ] : string | number | Item,
  id?: number,
}
```

In order to get this to work, I have to do:

```
interface Item {
  [ index: string ] : string | number | Item | undefined,
  id?: number,
}
```

Which I don't think I want all my other properties to be potentially undefined...  Is there another way to have `id` be optional?

**EDIT AGAIN**

Turns out even with the `| undefined` this doesn't work..  If I do the following:

```
let i : Item = { id: 123, foo: { bar: { id: 555} } };
console.log(i.foo.bar.id);
```

I get errors about "object is possibly undefined"

Comment: Does that not work?

Comment: @NoobLife I edited my question to give more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#:%7E:text=While%20string%20index,gives%20an%20error%3A), you can as long as the type of `id` is a subtype of `[index: string]`

```js
interface NumberDictionary {
  [index: string]: number;
     
  length: number; // ok
  name: string; // not ok
  // Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'number'.
}

interface NumberOrStringDictionary {
  [index: string]: number | string;
  length: number; // ok, length is a number
  name: string; // ok, name is a string
}
```

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if this is the best way but this seems to work

```js
interface Item1 {
  [ index: string ] : string | number | Item;
}

interface Item2 {
  id?: number;
}

type Item = Item1 & Item2
```

Also "object is possibly undefined" error can be solved with [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

```js
let i : Item = { id: 123, foo: { bar: { id: 555} } };
console.log(i.foo?.bar?.id);
```

Comment: See my edited question above..  What if length and name are to be optional?  As soon as I add `length?: number` I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Answer already provided by "noob" but extending a Record seems to work fine:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oCUIGMD2AnAJgDyK4CWAdgOYA0UJFlAPuQK4C2ARhLgHxQBkUAN4AoKOKil8AfgBcUVp24BuEQF9VIgDYQkwAAzy4iFMLESAZtmzyAjNXPiOAQ1zyARACZ36kdt1QwLZGCEioohKS+B627g6RVjZQ9o5QLm5QXj5qfjp6niEm4alSdvGW1mWp6R7eviJAA

```
type Test = Record<string, string|number> & {
    id?: number;
};

let t0: Test = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: "2"
}

let t1: Test = {
    id: "1",
    foo: 1,
    bar: "2"
}

let t2: Test = {
    id: 1,
    foo: 1,
    bar: "2"
}
```

You will see an error:

> Errors in code Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number |
> undefined'.

Comment: How would I allow nested objects with this approach?  `let t2: Test = { id: 1, xyz: { foo: 'bar' } }` does not work.

Comment: You'd add it to the Record.